# Hard error when attempting SFINAE with lambda that has trailing return type

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have seen answers on SO that explain why SFINAE doesn't work with lambda return types. I changed my design a little, but now receiving an even stranger error. I couldn't figure out what I am missing. Code is going to be compiled with C++11, 14 and 17. I have got a somewhat C++17 compatible `apply`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ...T>
struct S {
  std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> things;
  template <typename F>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
    typename std::invoke_result<
      std::apply<F, T...>, F, T...>::type, bool>::value,
      bool>::type
  find_if(const F &f) {
      return std::any_of(things.begin(), things.end(),
      [&](const std::tuple<T...> &t) {
          return std::apply(f, t);
      });
  }
  template <typename F>
  auto find_if(const F &f) -> decltype(std::declval<F>()(things.front())) {
      return std::any_of(things.begin(), things.end(),
      [&](const std::tuple<T...> &t) { return f(t); });
  }
};

void f() {
    S<int, float> s;
    auto l = [](const std::tuple<int, float> &) -> bool { return false; };
    s.find_if(l);
}
```

My purpose is to call the right predicate. If predicate has a single parameter of type `std::tuple<Ts...>`, then call it directly. If predicate parameter list matches to unpacked template parameter pack, call that one.

Both GCC and Clang complain about the first method, where `apply` isn't a type.

```
<source>:13:26: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Functor, class ... _ArgTypes> struct std::invoke_result'
   13 |       std::apply, F, T...>::type, bool>::value,
      |                          ^
<source>:13:26: note:   expected a type, got 'std::apply'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metafunction `std::invoke_result` expect as it's first parameter a type of something callable, and the types of the argument.

Unfortunately, `std::apply` is not a type, it's a function. Also, `std::apply` is made to use type deduction, so it's not sfinae friendly.

The solution would be to use the type of the callable instead of the call to apply.

```
template <typename ...T>
struct S {
    std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> things;

    template <typename F, typename std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, T...>, bool>, int> = 0>
    auto find_if(const F &f) -> bool {
        return std::any_of(things.begin(), things.end(),
        [&](const std::tuple<T...> &t) {
            return std::apply(f, t);
        });
    }
};
```

Also, your lambda should look like this:

```
[](int, float) -> bool { return false; };
```

This is because apply is decomposing the tuple.

Comment: Thanks! Right... `invoke_result` doesn't work like `result_of`.

Comment: @user1150609 even with `std::result_of` you would have hit the same issue. There is no syntax in the language that will permit you to send `std::apply<T, Args...>` like that.

Comment: That's also correct, I tried and failed :( I was thinking that `std::result_of<std::apply(F, T...)>::type` would work.

Comment: @user1150609 yeah, `std::result_of` was somewhat confusing, that's why it's getting removed.